# How to include chapters in LaTeX?

Tags: chapters, thesis

I have a document `document.tex` which looks something like this:

```
...
\begin{document}
...
\include{chap1}
...
\end{document}
```

I create a `.tex` file called `chap1.tex` which contains exactly the following:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{Plan A}
This chapter is your first plan...
\end{document}
```

When I compile I found errors that I cannot fix. Any helps please?

Comment: Don't have `\begin{document}..\end{document}` in it. Only the text you want included in your document.

Comment: Please try to always include compilable, but minimal examples (i.e. here is just the `\documentclas{...}` missing) and  the error messages you get (look in the `.log` file for lines starting with `!`). This helps the answers to identify the issue.

Comment: remove the space at \chapter{Plan A} ie. \chapter{PlanA} It works in my case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the extra `\begin{document}`..`\end{document}` inside `chap1.tex`. It doesn't belong there. There is just one *document* -- created from one or multiple source *files*. Removing the extra environment should fix the errors.

Comment: And yes it does fix the errors. Thank you for your help.